# PBKDF2 iterations

Tags: asp.net-mvc, password-hash

I am using simplemembershipprovider in ASP.NET for authentication.

Microsoft's built in crypto method (below) uses 1000 iterations when hashing passwords. Everyone says this is not enough, **so my question is:** how could I change this? Surely there is a simple way for me to change one number from 1000 to 100000? I don't want to produce my own security code because people say that for an inexperienced developer security code should be kept away. Do I just accept that 1000 is what it is?

```
/* =======================
     * HASHED PASSWORD FORMATS
     * =======================
     * 
     * Version 0:
     * PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations.
     * (See also: SDL crypto guidelines v5.1, Part III)
     * Format: { 0x00, salt, subkey }
     */

    public static string HashPassword(string password)
    {
        if (password == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("password");
        }

        // Produce a version 0 (see comment above) password hash.
        byte[] salt;
        byte[] subkey;
        using (var deriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, SaltSize, PBKDF2IterCount))
        {
            salt = deriveBytes.Salt;
            subkey = deriveBytes.GetBytes(PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        }

        byte[] outputBytes = new byte[1 + SaltSize + PBKDF2SubkeyLength];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(salt, 0, outputBytes, 1, SaltSize);
        Buffer.BlockCopy(subkey, 0, outputBytes, 1 + SaltSize, PBKDF2SubkeyLength);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(outputBytes);
    }
```